# How can I expose a C# Action declared in another class

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I would like to expose an Action declared in an Internal class in a public class

```
internal class A
{ 
     public Action OnEvent { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
     private A a = new A();

     public Action OnEvent 
     {
         get => a.OnEvent;
         set => a.OnEvent += value;    <- this is not correct

     }
}
```

I am looking for a property getter/setter which allows to write code like this:

```
var b = new B();
b.OnEvent += DoSomething;  // this should add DoSomething to B.a.OnEvent
...
b.OnEvent -= DoSomething;  // this should remove DoSomething from B.a.OnEvent
```

EDIT
One solution is to add

```
void Add(Action handler) 
{ a.OnEvent += handler}
```

and

```
void Remove(Action handler) 
{ a.OnEvent -= handler }
```

but I would like to use the += & -= syntax

Comment: I'm confused, do you just want to create an event?  Do you want to be able to access the subscribers to the event?

Comment: I want to be able to add and remove subscribers.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `public event EventHandler OnEvent` (or maybe this is the answer you're looking for)?

Comment: public delegate void OnEventHandler();
public event OnEventHandler OnEvent;
private A a = new A();
a.OnEvent += A_OnEvent; Can you try like this

Comment: @MikeH how would you add that to class B? what will be the setter and getter?

Comment: @RM. I'll write up some code as an answer

Comment: @HidayetR.Colkusu adding an event works as in my example above but removing is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it

```
public event Action OnEvent
    {
        add { a.OnEvent += value; }
        remove { a.OnEvent -= value; }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I don't think I've seen that one before.